Solving the Radially Symmetric Poisson Equation with Exponential Source Term
I want to solve the poisson equation
$$
-\Delta u(\mathbf{x})=\rho(\mathbf{x})=\frac{e^{-|\mathbf{x}|^2}}{|\mathbf{x}|^2-1}
$$
The problem want me to use the fundamental solution of laplace operator, namely $\frac{1}{4\pi|x-y|}$. I know that for such possion equation the solution is
$$
u(\mathbf{x})=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{1}{4\pi|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|}\cdot\frac{e^{-|\mathbf{y}|^2}}{|\mathbf{y}|^2-1}d^3y
$$
But I find this integral is very hard to be calculated in normal way I know. Any helps are appreciated.
